# Why am I getting a nokogiri and mini_portile2 dependency error when deploying to new Heroku server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deployment, nokogiri

I am trying to update my RoR application to run on new Heroku server.  I continue to get error:

```
'Downloading nokogiri-1.10.3 revealed dependencies not in the API or the lockfile
remote:        (mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)).
remote:        Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle 
update nokogiri` should
remote:        fix the problem. '.
```

Both mini_portile2 and nokogiri appear in the Gemfile and Gemfile.Lock.  It worked fine using older versions on older server.  The new verion works for me at home using rails server, showing no dependency issues.  I have verified and checked dependencies as much as I know how and have followed Heroku's advice of installing with '--full-index' and running 'bundle update nokogiri' numerous times.  What do I need to do to make it work?  I am using latest Cygwin and the latest Ruby and Rails versions with I believe the correct gems.  Windows 7.

1. `bundle install --full-index`      # no change
2. `bundle update nokogiri`           # no change
3. `gem install nokogiri`             # no change
4. `gem install nokogiri --system-dependencies`    # no change
5. `gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-xml2-config=/usr/include/libxml2 --with-xslt-config=/usr/include/libxslt`   # nochange
6. In Gemfile, I tried putting mini_portile2 on its own and in production group.        # no change

After each gem install, I update/install bundle.

Error:

```
remote:        Installing i18n 0.9.5
remote:        Downloading nokogiri-1.10.3 revealed dependencies not in the API or the lockfile
remote:        (mini_portile2 (~> 2.4.0)).
remote:        Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle             update nokogiri` should
remote:        fix the problem.
remote:
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to vast-sea-55538.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/vast-sea-55538.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/vast-sea-55538.git'
```

Gem File:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.6.3', :patchlevel => '62'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rake', '~>12.0'
gem 'rails', '4.2.8'

# rails_12factor is required by Heroku
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use production for AWS Beanstalk
# gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.10', group: :production

# Use development for Heroku
 gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.10', group: :development

# pg is required by Heroku
gem 'pg', '~>0.18.1', group: :production

# nokogiri dev dependencies

# gem 'concourse', '~> 0.24'
# gem 'hoe', '~> 3.17'
# gem 'hoe-bundler', '~> 1.2'
# gem 'hoe-debugging', '~> 2.0'
# gem 'hoe-gemspec', '~> 1.0'
# gem 'hoe-git', '~> 1.6'
# gem 'racc', '~> 1.4.14'
# gem 'rexical', '~> 1.0.5'
# gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.16'
# gem 'rake-compiler-dock', '~> 0.7.0'

# simplecov dependencies
# gem 'docile', '~> 1.1'
# gem 'simplecov-html', '~> 0.10.0'

# docile dependencies
# gem 'github-markup', '>= 0'
# gem 'redcarpet', '=> 0'
# gem 'yard', '=> 0'

# redcarpet dependencies
# gem 'test-unit', '~> 3.1.3'

# test-unit dependencies
# gem 'power_assert', '>= 0'
# gem 'kramdown', '>= 0'
# gem 'packnga', '>= 0'

# power_assert dependencies
# gem 'benchmark-ips', '>= 0'
# gem 'pry', '>= 0'

# pry dependencies
# gem 'coderay', '~> 1.1.0'
# gem 'method_source', '~> 0.9.0'

# kramdown dependencies
# gem 'rouge', '>= 0'
# gem 'stringex', '~> 1.5.1'

# stringex dependencies
# gem 'jeweler', '= 2.3.7'
# gem 'RedCloth', '= 4.2.9'
# gem 'travis-lint', '= 1.7.0'

# github-markup dependencies
# gem 'github-linguist', '>= 7.1.3'
# gem 'html-pipeline', '~> 1.0'
# gem 'nokogiri-diff', '>= 0.2.0'
# gem 'sanitize', '~> 2.1, >= 2.1.0'

# sanitize dependencies
# gem 'nokogumbo', '~> 2.0'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sassc'
gem 'sassc-rails'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more:         https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'json', '~> 2.1.0'
# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'rake-compiler', '~>1.0.3'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.12'
# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

gem 'mini_portile', '~> 0.6.2'

# mini_portile2 dependencies
# gem 'minitar', '~> 0.7'
# gem 'minitest-hooks', '~> 1.5.0'

# minitar dependencies
# gem 'hoe-doofus', '~> 1.0'
# gem 'hoe-gemspec2', '~>1.1'
# gem 'hoe-git', '~>1.6'
# gem 'hoe-rubygems', '~>1.0'
# gem 'hoe-travis', '~>1.2'
# gem 'minitest-autotest', '< 2, >= 1.0'

# minitest-autotest dependencies
# gem 'minitest-server', '~> 1.0'

# hoe-gemspec2 dependencies
# gem 'hoe-seattlerb', '>= 1.2'


# puma is required by AWS Beanstalk
# gem 'puma'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.1'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'mini_portile2', '~> 2.4.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Use RVM? What OS?

Comment: In ruby 2.6.5 its OK.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your Gemfile.lock was created on Mac Machine.
Heroku is running on Linux and nokogiri has additional dependencies there (mini_portile2).

`bundle lock --add-platform ruby`
added missing gem to gemfile.lock to me.

After adding ruby + `bundle install` I got:

```
 nokogiri (1.11.7)
    ⋮ 459│      mini_portile2 (~> 2.5.0)
    ⋮ 460│      racc (~> 1.4)
    ⋮ 461│    nokogiri (1.11.7-arm64-darwin)
    ⋮ 462│      racc (~> 1.4)
    ⋮ 463│    nokogiri (1.11.7-x86_64-linux)
 458⋮ 464│      racc (~> 1.4)
```

Side note: Actually it should install it for everything beside java https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.11.7/nokogiri.gemspec#L11
but it has some trouble with it.

Comment: Also this is might be relevant, showing the same solution but also adding Linux as a platform: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#bundler-2-2-3